# How to retrieve and display images in reactjs that are stored on the server side using multer and the path is stored in the database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, image, express, multer

I am having similar problem.I stored the path in database named Cast and the images on the server. The database has two fields name and image. In the react app,i want to display the image.I am not getting the image. 
I am running express on localhost:5000 and reactjs on localhost:3000.
Ex: image in the db has the value "Anushka.jpg". On the server side it is stored as follows:

```
public
 └─ cast_images 
     └─ Anushka.jpg
```

app.js file(server side)

```
app.use('/login', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
  Cast.find()
  .then(
    cast=>res.json(cast))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

App.js(frontend react file):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <br/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class Login extends Component {
  state={
    casts:[]
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/admin/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({casts:response.data});
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
    render() {
        const actor =this.state.casts.map(actor => {
          return (
             <p>
              <img src="/cast_images/{actor.image}" alt="hello"/>
              <h3>{actor.name}</h3>
            </p>
          );
        });
        return(<p>{actor}</p>);
    }
}
```

I did not not mention here imports in React code.This is a part of code.Can u please tell me how to get the image.Thanks in advance.

Comment: With this `app.use('/login', ...`, you are mapping `/loigin` to your static file path, try `app.use('/', ...` instead

Comment: Hey.Thank you so much for replying. I tried what you said and im still not able to access the image and one new thing i noticed is that in <img src="/cast_images/{actor.image}"> the value of actor.image is not getting replaced by the value stored in the database.

Comment: When i am hardcoding the image name as <img src="/cast_images/Anushka.jpg"> i am able to get image on localhost:5000(where my express is running) but not on localhost:3000(where my react app is running)

Comment: Then you have to prefix your path with your actual server base url. Also in react you can use "js template string literal" put a variable value in a string not the quote sign and dollar sign  `<img src={\`${serverBaseURI}/cast_images/${actor.image}\`} alt="hello"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code you are mounting your `public` folder to the `/login` url path, I don't think that is what you want

> `app.use('/login', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`

So it should be changed to

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

And in React, you can use JavaScript [template string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insert a variable inside a string.

```
const serverBaseURI = 'http://localhost:5000' // set this to the value of your express server, should be different value for production server
/* .... */
<img src={`${serverBaseURI}/cast_images/${actor.image}`} alt="hello"/>
```

Comment: But shouldn't it work on localhost:3000?I am just a little curious to know why it did not work on localhost:3000

Comment: Because your images are served from a http server not from your file system. That http server is managed by express on `localhost:5000`. You have instructed express to get your files from your file system by using `express.static`.